# How can I get IntelliJ to ignore formatting with Subversion?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, ide, formatting

I am using `IntelliJ 12 Ultimate`.  Each developer on our team likes to have their own spacing (2 chars, 4 chars, tabs, etc.).

I have this habit of pressing `ALT SHIFT F` many MANY times as I code.  I like the way it formats the code.  However, I use 4 chars for spacing and other people use 2.

What I would like to do is prevent IntelliJ and/or Subversion (1.7) to ignore that formatting change.  The first thing I do when I open someone else's code is press the `ALT SHIFT F` so I can read it (habit, I know).

This marks every line as "changed" in Subversion.

But it's essentially the exact same code.  Just formatted different.

How can I prevent this from happening?  What would be awesome is that when I opened up a file, it would auto-format but not register it as a change.  Only if I actually press the keyboard and change characters should it register as "edit", IMHO.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Subversion doesn't understand context or formatting. Changed bytes are changed bytes.

This is why having coding standards - and making sure everyone adheres to them - is so important on any project.

If everyone else is using 2 characters while you use 4, you either need to adapt, or you'll need to configure IntelliJ such that you can revert the formatting back to their preference (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, maybe, to make it easy to remember?) before you commit.